# WCF Service timing out when calling. Works fine with WcfTestClient

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcfserviceclient

so I have a WCF Web service hosted on IIS. I can invoke the methods from a remote pc using Wcftestclient and it works just fine with no error.

However when I call the web service function from a .net windows form or from visual fox pro, after around a minute both return with error:

> The operation has timed out

It seems  strange as wcftestclient works fine.

Can anyone help?

thanks

Comment: What happens when you browse to your svc file? For Example: "http://localhost/YourServiceHost/YourService.svc"

Comment: Hi I have fixed it, the issues was I was creating  Service1 webservice = new Service1(); instead of  Service1Client webservice = new Service1Client();